# NSMutableArray count is 0 after initWithObject

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've defined a property of `NSMutableArray`. Right after calling `initWithObjects`, it's `count` is 0. What am I missing here? Here's my code:

```
@interface MainViewController ()
@property NSMutableArray *photos;
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _photos = [_photos initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];
    NSLog(@"Photos count: %lu",(unsigned long)_photos.count); //prints 0
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `_photos` is `nil` at the time that you are trying to call the `init` method. Use `arrayWithObjects` instead:

```
_photos = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];
```

Answer (score 3):

It is *illegal* to say `init...` without saying `alloc` in the same line. `alloc` is a class method, and your class is NSMutableArray, so you should have said:

```
_photos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Only one can be accepted though :)